# How to handle file_get_contents when the response can be false

Tags: php

I'm working on calling an url that responds either `true` or `false`. I want to use `file_get_contents` but I don't know how to handle server errors.

```
$content = file_get_contents($url);
if ($content === false) {
  echo "Unexpected error in response at: {$url}\n";
  return false;
 } else {
     return json_decode($content);
```

The check on the `$content` is necessary because the server can respond 500 and `file_get_contents` in this case returns false.
But false is a valid response. So I'm asking if there is a better pattern to use in this case.
Thanks!

UPDATE (with fix):
After a while, I found that I should have returned just the `$content` and not the decoded content. Then I have to handle the decode later.

```
$content = file_get_contents($url);
if ($content === false) {
  echo "Unexpected error in response at: {$url}\n";
 }
 return $content;
```

Comment: Content is __string__. I suppose you can distinct `"false"` from `false`?

Comment: In fact the response is "false". I just had a bug in the logic when I returned the `json_decode($content)`. In that case, the return value was `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, there is an [empty()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function for php.

```
$content = file_get_contents($url);
if (empty($content)) {
  echo "Unexpected error in response at: {$url}\n";
 } else {
     return json_decode($content);
```

Comment: This does not work in my case. Anyway I found the bug. The code was working but I was calling it badly. Thanks

Comment: @AlessioIzzo it should work tho, that's the whole use of this code.

Comment: The check with `empty` works, but the problem was in the return statement. I should not decode the `$content` variable.